# Updating Azure Table Storage Field in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline in Azure Data Factory.
The Pipeline Includes 3 Activities.
1. Lookup ---> Get Content from Table Storage
2. Web Activity --> Call a REST Endpoint (parameter is passed from the result of the lookup activity)
3. Copy Activity --> Copy the REST response payload into CSV.

The thing is I need to flag the Table Storage Row as Success or Fail based on the Web Activity if it returned Response 200 or not.

So my question is that is there any Activity in Azure Data Factory that lets you update a Table storage field.

Comment: you can delete and recreate the record, since updating is not yet supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According my experience,  there isn't any Active in Data Factory support update a Table storage field for now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation for comment, that why I am writing in answer section.

Because there is no activity such as update a Table storage field, so this could be help you to solve your problem.
With `Update Entity` you can updates an existing entity in a table.

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That’s what I did. I added a web activity that calls a Logic App to update the record.